# How do I properly add this query into my existing query within Query Designer?

Tags: sql-server, query-designer

I currently have the below query written within Query Designer. I asked a question yesterday and it worked on its own but I would like to incorporate it into my existing report.

```
SELECT Distinct
       i.ProductNumber
  ,i.ProductType
  ,i.ProductPurchaseDate
  ,ih.SalesPersonComputerID
  ,ih.SalesPerson
  ,ic2.FlaggedComments

FROM [Products] i
        
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Distinct
        MIN(c2.Comments) AS FlaggedComments
        ,c2.SalesKey 
        FROM [SalesComment] AS c2
        WHERE(c2.Comments like 'Flagged*%')
        GROUP BY c2.SalesKey) ic2 
    ON ic2.SalesKey = i.SalesKey

LEFT JOIN [SalesHistory] AS ih
    ON ih.SalesKey = i.SalesKey

WHERE
  i.SaleDate  between @StartDate and @StopDate
AND ih.Status = 'SOLD'
```

My question yesterday was that I wanted a way to select only the first comment made for each sale. I have a query for selecting the flagged comments but I want both the first row and the flagged comment. They would both be pulling from the same table. This was the query provided and it worked on its own but I cant figure out how to make it work with my existing query.

```
SELECT a.DateTimeCommented, a.ProductNumber, a.Comments, a.SalesKey 
FROM (
    SELECT 
            DateTimeCommented, ProductNumber, Comments, SalesKey,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY DateTimeCommented) as RowN
    FROM [SalesComment]
    ) a 
WHERE a.RowN = 1
```

Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: That's SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I didnt know I had tagged it!

Comment: How does `SalesKey` relate to `ProductNumber`, and why are you grouping by one but partitioning by the other? Also why do you have `distinct` on this query, are there too many rows coming out of one of the joins? And that `LEFT JOIN [SalesHistory]` may as well be `INNER` because of the `WHERE`

Comment: SalesKey is the unique key and the product number is the product sold. I am really new to SSRS so I thought I had to put Distinct to only get one record of each. I will change the Sales History to Inner. Im really just learning as I go.

Comment: So you want the first `SalesComment` per `ProductNumber`, but you want to join on `SalesKey`? Doesn't sound quite right but if that's what you want...

Comment: The sales key is the unique number I used for all of them while I want the comment to be sorted by the Product Number. So, the first submitted comment for that product and then the flagged comment for that same product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of row-numbering and aggregation to get both the `Flagged%` comments, and the first comment.

You may want to change the `PARTITION BY` clause to suit.

> `DISTINCT` on the outer query is probably spurious, on the inner query it *definitely is*, as you have `GROUP BY` anyway. If you are getting multiple rows, don't just throw `DISTINCT` at it, instead think about your joins and whether you need aggregation.

> The second `LEFT JOIN` logically becomes an `INNER JOIN` due to the `WHERE` predicate. Perhaps that predicate should have been in the `ON` instead?

```sql
SELECT
   i.ProductNumber
  ,i.ProductType
  ,i.ProductPurchaseDate
  ,ih.SalesPersonComputerID
  ,ih.SalesPerson
  ,ic2.FlaggedComments
  ,ic2.FirstComments

FROM [Products] i
        
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        MIN(CASE WHEN c2.RowN = 1 THEN c2.Comments) AS FirstComments
        ,c2.SalesKey 
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN c2.Comments like 'Flagged*%' THEN c2.Comments) AS FlaggedComments
        FROM (
            SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY DateTimeCommented) as RowN
            FROM [SalesComment]
        ) AS c2
        GROUP BY c2.SalesKey
    ) ic2 ON ic2.SalesKey = i.SalesKey

JOIN [SalesHistory] AS ih
    ON ih.SalesKey = i.SalesKey

WHERE
  i.SaleDate between @StartDate and @StopDate
AND ih.Status = 'SOLD'
```